# Was drowning a form of mercy killing in Colonial America?

Tags: colonial-america, illness

In doing family history research I came across this death notice, "John French, his wife drown’d herself 13 May 1701."  Curious wording.  Last summer I visited the French-Andrews house, still standing in Topsfield, Mass. The current owner suggested she must have been terminally ill and that her husband/family drowned her as a form of mercy killing.? He also said this was a known practice in Colonial America.  Try as I may, I have been unable to find any sort of reference to such a practice.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems unlikely, considering prevalent Christian morality at that time, stigma on suicide and of course murder.

Comment: She could literally have drowned herself if she couldn't swim - just take a boat out onto a deep-enough lake and jump into the water. Reasons for suicide are of course personal, but she could easily have had depression (post-partum or otherwise) or been trapped in a very unhappy and/or abusive marriage.

Comment: Extremely unlikely. Until very recently Christian morals strictly forbade suicide and assisted suicide. Not to mention the experience itself is gruesome. Try it for yourself. It's called "waterboarding".

Comment: Not a direct answer but maybe of interest: "Massachusetts... passed a statute in 1660 outlawing suicide and requiring contemptuous burial of a suicide's corpse on a public highway with 'a Cart-load of Stones laid upon the Grave as a Brand of Infamy, and as a warning to others to beware of the like Damnable practices.' This statute was not repealed until 1823... " [(source)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1306612/)

Comment: [Suicide by drowning](https://archive.nytimes.com/www.nytimes.com/learning/general/onthisday/bday/0125.html) is far from unknown.